# Change the root password of a Linux image

Tags: linux, compiling, password

I'm building a jessie build of Debian. Passwords are saved in `/etc/shadow` in the build tree, but they are salted obviously so I cannot change it just by editing the file. If this was my installed system, I could call `passwd`, but here I want to change the password in the file in the build tree.

How do I change the root password before I flash a SD with a new build?

Comment: Just `chroot` into the image, run `passwd`, then do the copy. If it's a debian image the rootfs is probably `squash`ed, you'll want to unsquash/resquash before/after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the stage where you have a directory tree containing a file `…/etc/shadow` (before building the filesystem image), modify that file to inject the password hash(es) that you want to have.

The easiest way to do that is with recent enough versions of the [`chpasswd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chpasswd) tool from the Linux shadow utilities suite (Debian wheezy is recent enough) with the `-R` option. Sample usage:

```
chpasswd -R /path/to/build/tree <passwords.txt
```

with `passwords.txt` containing lines like

```
root:swordfish
alibaba:opensesame
```

If your build environment doesn't support `chpasswd -R`, you can use a tool that generates a password hash by calling the [`crypt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) function and inject that into the `shadow` file by text manipulation. For example (untested code):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import base64, crypt, os, re, sys
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    (username, password) = line.strip().split(":")
    salt = "$6$" + base64.b64encode(os.urandom(6))
    hashes[username] = crypt.crypt(password, salt)
old_shadow = open("etc/shadow")
new_shadow = open("etc/shadow.making", "w")
for line in old_shadow.readlines():
    (username, password, trail) = line.lstrip().split(":", 3)
    if hashes.has_key(username):
        line = username + ":" + hashes[username] + ":" + trail
    new_shadow.write(line)
old_shadow.close()
new_shadow.close()
os.rename("etc/shadow.making", "etc/shadow")
```